# How to resolve this circulary dependancy with python enums

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, enums

So I have 2 enumerations, the problem is that the first enumration is referencing the second and the second is referencing it too.

```py
    from enum import Enum
    
    class UniverseData:
        def __init__(self, name, coordinate, civilisations)
            self.civilisation_name = name
            self.coordinate = coordinate
            self.civilisation = civilisations
    
    class CivilisationData:
        def __init__(self, name, population_cap, universe)
            self.name = name
            self.population_cap = population_cap
            self.universe = universe
    
    class Universe(Enum):
        Yievdal = UniverseData('Yievdal', 'X258RC', [Civilisation.HUMANITY, Civilisation.ERG, Civilisation.ELF])
        Krastam = UniverseData('Krastam', 'X258BC', [Civilisation.MOJNA, Civilisation.CELES])
    
    class Civilisation(Enum):
        HUMANITY = CivilisationData('humanity', '11B', Universe.Yievdal)
        ERG = CivilisationData('erg', '2B', Universe.Yievdal)
        ELF = CivilisationData('elf', '2B', Universe.Yievdal)
        MOJNA = CivilisationData('mojna', '50B', Universe.Krastam)
        CELES = CivilisationData('celes', '110B', Universe.Krastam)
```

here the problem is that the Universe enumeration cannot use the Civilisation enumeration since it is declared below.

is there no way around this? I'd like to be able to have the all the universe civilisation in the universe enum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe just leave the `civilisation` attribute in definition and assign it after the `Civilisation` class has also been defined, this prevents the circular problem. I've shown a possible way but you could just write a function that loops through each attribute of the `Universe` class and assigns a `civilisation`.

```
from enum import Enum

class UniverseData:
    def __init__(self, name, coordinate, civilisations=None)
        self.civilisation_name = name
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.civilisation = civilisations

class CivilisationData:
    def __init__(self, name, population_cap, universe)
        self.name = name
        self.population_cap = population_cap
        self.universe = universe

class Universe(Enum):
    Yievdal = UniverseData('Yievdal', 'X258RC')
    Krastam = UniverseData('Krastam', 'X258BC')

class Civilisation(Enum):
    HUMANITY = CivilisationData('humanity', '11B', Universe.Yievdal)
    ERG = CivilisationData('erg', '2B', Universe.Yievdal)
    ELF = CivilisationData('elf', '2B', Universe.Yievdal)
    MOJNA = CivilisationData('mojna', '50B', Universe.Krastam)
    CELES = CivilisationData('celes', '110B', Universe.Krastam)


Universe.Yievdal.civilisation = [Civilisation.HUMANITY, Civilisation.ERG, Civilisation.ELF]
Universe.Krastam.civilisation = [Civilisation.MOJNA, Civilisation.CELES]
```

Comment: it works but I don't understand why, this code is in `src.common`.

in an other script I do `from src.common import Universe, Civilisation`.

but since I'm just importing `Universe` and `Civilisation`, what is executing the code that adds the civilisations into the `Univese` enum?

Comment: @sliders_alpha: When a module is imported, the top-level code is executed; this means that top-level functions are defined, top-level class bodies are run, and enums are created.  This is why it's a bad idea to put expensive operations at the top level; instead put them in a function that can be called at the appropriate time.

Comment: there is one downside to this, impossible to do comparaison after that.

I have to use universe_variable.name == Universe.Yievdal.name, but before I could do it without name

Answer (score 1):

In python you cannot reference class's field until you declare class.

So, you need  define `class Civilisation` before usage like this.

```
from enum import Enum


class UniverseData:
    def __init__(self, name, coordinate, civilisations):
        self.civilisation_name = name
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.civilisation = civilisations


class CivilisationData:
    def __init__(self, name, population_cap, universe):
        self.name = name
        self.population_cap = population_cap
        self.universe = universe


class Universe(Enum):
    Yievdal = UniverseData('Yievdal', 'X258RC', [])
    Krastam = UniverseData('Krastam', 'X258BC', [])


class Civilisation(Enum):
    HUMANITY = CivilisationData('humanity', '11B', Universe.Yievdal)
    ERG = CivilisationData('erg', '2B', Universe.Yievdal)
    ELF = CivilisationData('elf', '2B', Universe.Yievdal)
    MOJNA = CivilisationData('mojna', '50B', Universe.Krastam)
    CELES = CivilisationData('celes', '110B', Universe.Krastam)


Universe.Yievdal.civilisations = [Civilisation.HUMANITY, Civilisation.ERG, Civilisation.ELF]
Universe.Krastam.civilisations = [Civilisation.MOJNA, Civilisation.CELES]
```